# ListView titles is getting wrapped and appears dis aligned

Tags: android, listview

Im trying to create a ListView with three columns and Im using custom adapter as well.

Following is my row.xml.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/taskNameValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="TaskName"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dueDateValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Due Date"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ageingValue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="Ageiging"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


Following is my compliance.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/taskNameLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Task Name"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dueDateLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Due Date"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ageingLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Ageing"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that title is not properly aligned as you could see from the screenshot. The title `Due Date` appears dis aligned and also Ageing appears wrapped. How can I be able to sort this out?

[image]

i have even tried using weight sum yet the problem persists.

Comment: May be you need to decrease `Text` size.

Comment: your compliance.xml is really messed up first sort that out

Comment: give the specific height to text views and reduce your text size